# Anything to do about "retaliation" downvotes?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes downvotes may not be serial downvoting but they are clearly done as a form of retaliation and have little (or nothing) to do with the downvoter's opinion about the content of your post.

Our policy about downvotes has this to say:

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Today I downvoted an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51843241/1767412) because it makes a factually incorrect statement and provides a sub-optimal workaround for a situation not really related to the question. I believe the suggestion made by the answerer is incorrect and according to our policy, this is why downvotes exist.  Moments later my own answer was suddenly downvoted alongside the other poster's last activity of "3 minutes ago".  Given the age and relatively low activity of the question I think my assumption about what happened is almost certainly valid.

As far as I can see, I received a downvote that goes against policy but will doubtfully get flagged as serial down-voting.

**EDIT:** This question is about *single, one-off* retaliation votes.  These are, according to our published policy, not ok.  This is not a question about policy, neither is it a question about a flood of downvotes.

Comment: I mean... you left a comment on said answer, thus prompting the answerer to be notified of said comment, at which point they were free to evaluate your answer. For all you or we know, they simply found it to be not useful. No one can prove otherwise. Nothing needs to be done here.

Comment: Retaliation downvoting can only be the explanation if you somehow let people know that you did downvote. Otherwise it is tactical downvoting, badquestion-answer downvoting or any number of other (more or less correct) reasons for downvoting. Vote anonymously if you are afraid, the system protects you. Vote with explanation to imporove StackOverflow as whole, if you are brave.

Comment: @billynoah There's not such thing like _abusive downvotes_ beyond serial voting:

Comment: You really should have left off the last sentence in your comment on the other person's answer. Discussing downvoting like that on main is off-topic and unlikely to lead to anything good.

Comment: From the meta post: `Don't worry. There is a system in place which will pick this issue up (at 3am UTC) and will reverse it. There is nothing you need to do`

Comment: @Yunnosch - Of course there can be no proof.  But I would like to make a $50,000 wager that it was retaliation

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure there is.  Just because it's often unenforceable when someone is voting on something other than the content of the post doesn't mean it's not abusive, it just means there's nothing that we can do to stop the abuse.  You can still recognize that it is abusive, and tell people not to do it, even though you can't punish them for doing it.

Comment: @divibisan A single vote is never going to be reversed.

Comment: Maybe if you offer that bet in a comment, the downvoter will speak up and explain the reason.

Comment: @Yunnosch Speaking for myself, if I downvoted a post because I thought it was a bad post, and someone commented that they'd bet $50k that the vote was a retaliatory vote, there's no way I would *ever* comment on that post, because they're clearly not looking for a constructive discussion on the topic.

Comment: @Servy Good point.

Comment: @Servy I seriously have to disagree. It's everyone's genuine right here to vote on posts. And if it was because I lost my keys, that's just my business, and not anyone else's.

Comment: @Servy - my answer is not a bad answer. It is, to the best of my knowledge, the "*correct*" answer.  The wager was a joke of course, and if there's something wrong that genuinely merits a downvote I'm eager to know what it is.

Comment: @billynoah What's the point about worrying about a single downvote at all? Can you explain that in depth please?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - thanks.  I took your advice and updated my comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, it's your **privilege**, not right, **privilege**, to reflect your opinion on whether or not you think a given post is useful.  Using that vote for things other than your opinion of the usefulness of the post is violating the rules.  Of course, no one can do anything about it, because there's rarely ever a way of knowing if someone is voting based on the posts usefulness or not, but you don't have the right to downvote posts because you lost your keys, we just can't *know* if you're downvoting a post because you lost your keys.

Comment: @Servy I think a lotta posts aren't useful for future research, other's think different (maybe less abstract), that's all perfectly OK IMO.

Comment: @billynoah In my experiences the people who assume a downvote cast on their answer could only ever have been a retaliatory downvote, rather than considering that the voter may have simply thought that the answer wasn't a good answer (even if they're wrong in what they think is problematic about it, or you disagree that it's a problem) is rarely open to the possibility that they're wrong.  People like to say that they want to hear what's problematic about their posts, until someone tells them, then they just get upset.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, you're given *very* wide freedoms to interpret "usefulness" of a post.  It's perfectly okay for you to honestly think that a post isn't useful for things that a lot of other people wouldn't expect to affect the usefulness of a post, or vice versa.  No one can tell you what you think is or is not useful, just what they think is useful, or what they've found useful in the past.  But if you're voting a on a post in a way that conflicts *your own opinion of the usefulness of the post* then you've done something wrong (although again, it's often unenforceable).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I use Select2 regularly in a few applications and this is a common enough issue that I am positive the question will get hits.  The downvote coupled with the asker's decision to mark the other answer as "correct" decreases the likelihood of people in the future benefiting from the API option which was precisely designed to deal with this.

Comment: @Servy I never would vote conflicting with my own opinion, that would be totally nuts, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you downvote a post because you think the author downvoted you, and you're upset at them, then you're voting based on something other than the usefulness of the post.  If you're voting on the answer because it's a competing answer and you just want yours higher in the ranking, that's not based on the usefulness of the post.  While I believe you saying you wouldn't do those things, other people do, and they are casting abusive votes when they do it, even though most instances of it aren't enforceable due to lack of evidence.

Comment: @Servy OK, I am not doing such silly things. And yes, I already noticed such done for my posts several times in the past.

Comment: A retaliatory downvote from time to time is kind a fact of life, not much ado about it.

Comment: Since I made this post I've now become the target of an careful and occasional serial downvoter.  No comments, no explanation - just random old Q&A suddenly receiving downvotes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're just *guessing* that that person downvoted you.  You're also *guessing* as to why they downvoted you.  While an SE employee could see who cast the downvote, they have no possible way of knowing whether the vote was cast because the voter thinks the post isn't useful or because they don't like you.  They would need to have compelling evidence that the voter wasn't voting on the posts content in order to reverse a vote, evidence that they can't possibly have.

Answer (score 11):

Look at it from this angle.

You have over 9,000 reputation right now.  A downvote costs you 2 reputation.  That is around 0.02219% of your total reputation.

You shouldn't feel it *this* much.  People downvote for any reason they wish, and while it can suck, it's not the end of the world.

While I don't doubt it'd be different if you had a lot less reputation...what else can you realistically do?  You can't punish someone for tacitly exercising their voting powers*, nor does it make sense to ask a moderator to, either.

I wouldn't sweat this one.

<sup>*: If they downvote every other post you've made, a script will clean it up later.</sup>

Comment: Thanks - I understand your point.  I don't care about the rep.  I *do* care about the future users of Select2 benefiting from my answer.  That's the only reason it bothers me.

Comment: *"If they downvote every other post you've made, a script will clean it up later."* <- Except if the downvoter troll knows this and gives you only 3 downs, but every day...